# How can I call timeline-specific methods from an external file in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm creating a game is Flash CS5 with ActionScript 3. To simplify things, I've created a file (Game.as) in the top layer of my source folder. My Game.as file looks as follows:

```
package {
    public class Game {
        public static function fail():void {
            stop();

            var restart:RestartButton = new RestartButton();
            addChild(restart);

            restart.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            restart.y = stage.stageHeight/2;

            Game.createButton(restart, function(e:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndPlay (1, "Title Sequence") });
        }
    }
}
```

I would supposedly call `Game.fail ()` from a frame on a timeline a scene, but I get these compiler errors:

`Line 11 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method stop.
Line 19 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay.
Line 17 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Line 16 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Line 14 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.`

Why are these errors happening? What can I do to fix them?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that none of those methods exist on your `Game` class.

There's at least two good reasons for this:

1. Your `Game` class needs to extend `MovieClip` to have the methods `stop()`, `gotoAndPlay()`, `addChild()`, and the `stage` property. For example `class Game extends MovieClip` would give you those methods.
2. Even if your `Game extends MovieClip` you can't access methods like `stop()` from `static` scope, only from instance scope (ie `this`). This is because `static` scope is essentially a global code space so none of those methods make any sense:  when you say `stop()` you have to say *what* instance will stop, ex `this.stop()` or `thatThing.stop()`. The static code has no awareness of what instances of the class there may even be, so there's no way an instance function can work. You need an instance of the `Game` class, not just a static function.

What I think you are trying to do is essentially use `Game` as a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your main timeline. You can do that like this:

```
package {
    public class Game extends MovieClip {

        // global reference to a single instance of the Game
        public static game:Game;

        public function Game() {
            // store a global reference to this instance
            // NOTE: bad things will happen if you create more than one Game instance
            game = this;
        }

        // do NOT use static for your methods
        public function fail():void {
            stop();

            var restart:RestartButton = new RestartButton();
            addChild(restart);

            restart.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            restart.y = stage.stageHeight/2;

            createButton(restart, function(e:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndPlay (1, "Title Sequence") });
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to set this class as your [**document class**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233). There is only ever one instance of the document class, so this works well for you. However, you *could* link this class to a symbol in your library and instantiate it by code (`new Game()`) or by placing a timeline instance on a keyframe.

Finally, to call `Game` methods from *anywhere* you can use the `Game.game` instance:

```
Game.game.fail();
```

Comment: This is not a singleton (a comment that says "please don't instantiate this twice" does not make it a singleton) and even if it was a proper singleton (by enforcing the single instance) it would be unnecessary. The document class is all that's needed.

Comment: @null This *is* the singleton *pattern*. ActionScript does not support private constructors so does not have singletons as a language feature.  Any other singleton implementation (internal class args, throwing errors) is a hack and, in my opinion, esoteric in this context. The question is simple, so is my answer.

Comment: The singleton pattern enforces that only a single instance of a class can exist. Your code does not do this, so it's not a singleton. I fail to see how this makes anything simpler, as the whole part of the answer related to the (pseudo) singleton pattern is unnecessary. The singleton is forced here and an excuse to get some references via static members. Bad design. And there can very well be multiple instances of a document class...

Comment: ActionScript cannot enforce a single instance because there are no private constructors. Throwing an error in the constructor is helpful but entirely unnecessary when using the Document class, as suggested in this article. It is pedantic and unhelpful to say the lack of `throw error` which will *never* be encountered means this is "not a singleton". Post your own answer if you like, please.

Comment: As3 can enforce a single instance with the internal class as you mentioned. I do think it's helpful and not pedantic at all to point out if this code is what it's supposed to be or not. I think your answer is great, well the part that suggests using the document class.